# Find all files that contain a given clause in their names

Tags: command-line, find

This is a general question but my case is that I have installed (I beleive it got installed!) the gcc arm compiler but I can not find it anywhere in my system. I tried the command below but it returns almost anything

```
$sudo find . -print | grep -i '.*[arm]'
```

I beleive the file that I am looking for may have the following clauses in its name:

```
gcc, arm, eabi, 4.8, ....
```

What would be the best search term?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us how you installed the compiler. We may have a clue as to where to look.

Comment: FYI, in regex, `[arm]` isn't a "term", it's a set of individual characters. So your `grep` will match any name containing an a,r, or m. As well, `grep` isn't even needed, since `find` can match filenames either using shell glob syntax or regex syntax.

Comment: @Jos I just followed here https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-arm-embedded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-name` or `-iname` switches of `find` instead of `grep`ping `find`'s output; also you could narrow the search down to files, and if you have no idea about where it could have been installed you'd better search in `/` rather than in whichever is your current working directory:

```
sudo find / -type f -name "*gcc*" -o -name "*arm*" -o -name "*eabi*" -o -name "*4.8*"
```

---

As per [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643112/find-all-files-that-contain-a-given-clause-in-their-names/643114?noredirect=1#comment921000_643112), you installed it using a PPA, so if the executable has been added to your path you should be able to determine its location by running `which arm-none-eabi-gcc`; if it hasn't, run `sudo find / -type f -name "*arm-none-eabi-gcc*"`, it should be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks, but this also includes folder names, I am interested to find the compilers executable file only! there are many folders and header files and stuff that contains these names and I am not interested in

Comment: @Saeid87 It doesn't include folder names, however if you installed it via PPA as per [your comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643112/find-all-files-that-contain-a-given-clause-in-their-names/643114?noredirect=1#comment921000_643112), run `which arm-none-eabi-gcc`; if it doesn't ouput the location of the executable then run `sudo find / -name "*arm-none-eabi-gcc*"`, which should show at least the directory in which it has been installed.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the package and ran: `dpkg-query -L gcc-arm-none-eabi`. The result was a list of files, the most relevant of which was a number of files in `/usr/bin/` all starting with `arm-none-eabi`. I think those are the files you are looking for.

```
    $ls /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi*
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-addr2line   /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcov
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ar          /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-as          /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gprof
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-c++         /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-c++filt     /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld.bfd
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-cpp         /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-elfedit     /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++         /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc         /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ranlib
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9.3   /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-readelf
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar      /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-size
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc-nm      /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-strings
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib  /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-strip
```

Answer (score 1):

That `find` command should work:

```
find . -executable -type f -regex '.*\/[^\/]*\(gcc\|arm\|eabi\|4\.8\)[^\/]*'
```

Explanation:

- `-executable`: only matches files which have the executable bit set.
- `-type f`: only match regular files.
- `-regex ...`: search for the regular expression. You want only basenames, not whole parths, so we have to exclude slashes (`/`) behind at least one slash.